# Heat conduction through hollow cylinder with constant internal and external temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, vector-fields, calculus, heat-conduction

Consider a hollow cylinder of inner radius $r_1$ and outer radius $r_2$. The entire surface of the cylinder is kept at constant (but distinct) temperatures along the interior and exterior.

I found that the steady state temperature function is (in cylindrical coordinates)
$$T = -kr_2 \log \left(\frac{r}{r_1}\right) + T_0.$$

I am then asked to find the heat flux through a Gaussian cylinder of radius $r\in (r_1,r_2)$. The answer given is that the flux per unit length $\phi$ is
$$\phi = 2\pi r h_r,$$
where $h_r$ is the $r$ component of $\nabla \mathbf{h}$ (in cylindrical coordinates). My question is, how is this consistent with Gauss' Theorem (Divergence Theorem)? Because I found that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{h} = 0$, so shouldn't the flux be
$$\iint_S \mathbf{h}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{S} = \iiint_V \nabla\cdot \mathbf{h}\, \mathrm{d}V = \iiint_V 0\, \mathrm{d}V = 0?$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are that h is temperature T, right?  You should be applying the divergence theorem to the gradient of h, not h.

Comment: Wait, what do you mean? $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{h}$ is the divergence of $\mathbf{h}$. The divergence of the gradient of $\mathbf{h}$ is the Laplacian of $\mathbf{h}$; why do I want to use that?

Comment: Because the steady state heat conduction equation is Laplacian of temperature equal to zero.

Comment: But $\mathbf{h}$ is the heat, not the temperature... $T$ is the temperature.

Comment: What are the units of h and phi?

Comment: $\mathbf{h}$ is the "vector form of heat" with $\text{J/s$\cdot$m}^2$. $\phi$ is flux per unit length, so $\text{J/s$\cdot$m}$ I'm guessing. Sorry, the question (and the content in general) aren't very clear on the units.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct development:  $$\phi=2\pi r q_r$$where $q_r$ is the rate of heat flow per unit area in the radial direction:  $$q_r=-k\frac{dT}{dr}$$where k is the thermal conductivity of the annular cylinder.  These combine to give $$\frac{dT}{dr}=-\frac{\phi}{2\pi rk}$$integrating between $r_1$ and r gives:$$T-T_1=\frac{\phi}{2\pi k}\ln{(r_1/r)}$$The parameter $\phi$ can be obtained by applying the boundary condition at $r_2$:
$$\phi=2\pi k\frac{(T_1-T_2)}{\ln{(r_2/r_1)}}$$

Comment: Sorry, but I think you may have misunderstood my question. My problem isn't how we get from $\phi = 2\pi r h_r$ onwards; it is how we get to $\phi = 2\pi r h_r$ in the first place. Basically, I want to know how $\iiint_V \nabla\cdot \mathbf{h}\, \mathrm{d}V$ is evaluated (properly; not just handwaving that 'area is whatever') _so that_ $\phi = 2\pi r h_r$.